# How to launch more than four instances with local-SSD storage?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a cluster with more than 4 instances, each has one local-SSD. But I get this error:

```
Quota 'LOCAL_SSD_TOTAL_GB exceeded. Limit: 1500.0
```

I tried to decrease the local SSD storage to suppress this error but the box is grayed out to the a fixed value 375 GB. Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From GCE public documentation for Local SSD devices:

> ## Pricing and quota
>
> > Local SSDs are billed at a different rate than persistent disk. Refer to >>Compute Engine Pricing for more information.
> >
> > **By default, all projects are limited to four local SSD devices per region.**
> >     If you need more local SSDs for your project, you can request more quota.

To request for a [Quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas), use this [form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1vb2MkAr9JcHrp6myQ3oTxCyBv2c7Iyc5wqIKqE3K4IE/viewform)